# A function that compares strings of names within an array and not case sensitive

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, c-strings, toupper

In my homework, I need to make a function that take 10 names and compares them, telling me if the names are the same or not.

First, I made a function that puts the names in an array, then I made a function that checks if they are the same or not.

For the beginning, I made a function to check letter after letter if is similar or not:

```c
int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i=0,diff=0;
    for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if( toupper(s1[i])!=toupper(s2[i]) )
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I made a function to check the strings, name after name:

```c
int cheak ()
{
    int k;
    int j=SIZE;
    for(k=0;k<MAX;k++)
        for(j=MAX;j>=k;j--)
        {
            if(1==stringCmpi(names[k],names[j]))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
}
```

In the `main` I do:

```c
if(cheak(names)==1)
{
    printf("\nyou repeat names\n");
}
if(cheak(names!=1))
{
    printf("\n great! the names are not repeat\n");
}
```

But something in my code is wrong because it compiles but is not working. So, please help me - I would appreciate it.

Comment: The goal of a programming course is to learn programming... So learn how to debug a software, execute yours step by step and you will probably find out what the problem is.

Comment: @עידן רפאל דיי Show the array of strings definition.

Comment: `if( toupper(s1[i])!=toupper(s2[i]) )` - what if the strings have different length? When `s2` is shorter then `s1`?

Comment: You should indent your code properly. Your first code snippet is indented properly, the other two are not.

Comment: `if(cheak(names!=1))` - This looks suspect

Comment: @KamilCuk If `s2` is shorter, the check will be OK (see answer), but there needs to be a check if `s2` is longer.

Answer (score 3):

As KamilCuk has said in the comments, one *significant* problem you have is when the strings you are comparing have different lengths. Without using the standard library functions (which is, I guess, your goal), you can check for this by looking for `nul` terminators in different places in your compare function.

Here's one way to do that:

```c
int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i; // =0,diff=0; /// You don't use "diff" and "i" is initialized in the for loop!
    for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if( toupper(s1[i])!=toupper(s2[i]) ) // This check will catch situations where...
            return 1; // ... s2 is SHORTER than s1, as s2[i] will be '\0' and s1 won't be!
    }
    // But we need to catch if s2 is LONGER than s1: s1[i] will now be '\0'...
    // ... so we can just check that s2[i] is ALSO '\0' (i.e. it's same length):
    if (s2[i] != '\0') return 1; // Different length strings!
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

EDIT/PS: Also, as Ed Heal has mentioned, the comparison: `if(cheak(names!=1))` is very suspect - probably just a typo, where you meant `if(cheak(names)!=1)`. However, it would be much easier here just to use `else`!

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the function `stringCmpi`.

```
int stringCmpi (char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i=0,diff=0;
    for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if( toupper(s1[i])!=toupper(s2[i]) )
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and let's assume that `s1` is `"A"` and `s2` is `"AB"`. In this case the function returns 0 because the loop will stop its iteration after comparing the first character `'A'` of the both string.

So this function is incorrect.

Now let's consider the function `cheak`

```
int cheak ()
{
int k;
int j=SIZE;
for(k=0;k<MAX;k++)
  for(j=MAX;j>=k;j--)
{
   if(1==stringCmpi(names[k],names[j]))
{
   return 0;
}
   return 1;
}
}
```

It seems that the identifier MAX means the number of strings in the array. In this case the index with the value MAX specifiers a non-existent string because the valid range of indices is `[0, MAX)`. SO the function already has undefined behavior.

If two names are unequal you at once exit the function though the array can conatin equal names. So the function can return a wrong result.

What you need is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int stringCmpi( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 != '\0' && 
            toupper( ( unsigned char )*s1 ) == toupper( ( unsigned char )*s2 ) )
    {
        ++s1; ++s2;
    }

    return *s1 != *s2;
} 

int check( size_t m, size_t n, char  names[const m][n] )
{
    int unique = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0 ; unique && i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; unique && j < m; j++ )
        {
            unique = stringCmpi( names[i], names[j] );
        }
    }

    return unique;
}


int main(void) 
{
    {
        enum { M = 3, N = 10 };
        char names[M][N] = { "Bob", "Tome", "David" };

        if( check( M, N, names ) )
        {
            printf( "\ngreat! the names are not repeat\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nyou repeat names\n" );
        }           
    }

    {
        enum { M = 3, N = 10 };
        char names[M][N] = { "Bob", "Tome", "Bob" };

        if( check( M, N, names ) )
        {
            printf( "\ngreat! the names are not repeat\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nyou repeat names\n" );
        }           
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
great! the names are not repeat

you repeat names
```

Or if your compiler does not support variable length arrays then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define M   3
#define N   10

int stringCmpi( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 != '\0' && 
            toupper( ( unsigned char )*s1 ) == toupper( ( unsigned char )*s2 ) )
    {
        ++s1; ++s2;
    }

    return *s1 != *s2;
} 

int check( char names[][N], size_t m )
{
    int unique = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0 ; unique && i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; unique && j < m; j++ )
        {
            unique = stringCmpi( names[i], names[j] );
        }
    }

    return unique;
}

int main(void) 
{
    {
        char names[M][N] = { "Bob", "Tome", "David" };

        if( check( names, M ) )
        {
            printf( "\ngreat! the names are not repeat\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nyou repeat names\n" );
        }           
    }
    {
        char names[M][N] = { "Bob", "Tome", "Bob" };

        if( check( names, M ) )
        {
            printf( "\ngreat! the names are not repeat\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nyou repeat names\n" );
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Well spotted for the `MAX` problem, Vlad! Something I **totally** missed. +1

Comment: @עידןרפאלדיין You can declare the function for example the following way/ #define N 10  int check( names[][N], size_t m );